# Razor Pages: passing more than one parameter to while navigation OnGetAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I work on Razor Page project that represents models `Lists` and `Records`:

```
public class List
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Title should be in range between 3 and 25")]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]

    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Record> Records { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Word should be in range between 3 and 25")]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]

    public string Word { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Translation should be in range between 3 and 30")]
    public string Translation { get; set; }

    public int ListId { get; set; }
    public List List { get; set; }
}
```

**Record** is a child of a **List**. One to Many in DB:
[image]

I built the valid url while opening the List Of `Records` from `Lists`:
[image]

Now I want to build the similar URL for a single `Record` that looks like this:
[image]
However, to do that I need to pass properly more than one parameter: `ListId` and `RecordId` by `csgtml` file. Something like this:

```
  <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID,@item.ListId">Details</a>
```

and signature of method `OnGetAsync` in Records/Details (the page I want to navigate) should look like this:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id, int? listId) {...}
```

Definition of page in `Records/Details.cshtml` should look similar to this:

```
@page "/Lists/{listId}/Records/{id}/Details/"
```

But it does not work!

If I define `@page Records/Details.cshtml` like this:

```
@page "/Lists/{id}/Records/Details/"
```

Method

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id, int? listId)
```

goes to the break point, however, both parameters are nulls and URL looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You’re almost there with this, but you need to split those route parameters and use something like this:

```
<a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID" asp-route-listId="@item.ListId">Details</a>
```

You use `asp-route-*` to set your parameters, where * represents the name of the parameter itself and is used for each individual parameter.

Comment: It’s covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.1#asp-route-value).

Answer (score 5):

If you need to specify multiple route values, you can use the `asp-all-route-data` attribute on the anchor tag helper:

```
@{   
    var routeValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
           { "listId", item.ListId },
           { "id", item.ID }
        };
}

<a asp-page="./Details" asp-all-route-data="routeValues">Click</a>
```